# Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. Redux action file

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-i18next

I am using `react-i18next` module and `useTranslation` hook translation. I am able to use it on my components. But I want to use it inside a redux action.`Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.`. 
 [Documentation of react-i18next](https://react.i18next.com/guides/quick-start)

```
import cogoToast from "cogo-toast";
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";

export const test = ({ key1, key2 }) => (dispatch) => {
    try {
        //api call
        const { t } = useTranslation();
        cogoToast(t("Hello"))
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: share some code

Comment: @PunitMakwana please check

Comment: The error message is the answer to your quesiton. Hooks are only used inside the body  of function components that are defined under the scope of react.

Comment: move `useTranslation()` inside of a component and then pass `t` to the action creator.

Comment: @marzelin, it works!. But I have multiple actions calls in several files. So by using this method I need to import the translator on every single file. Is there any alternative

Comment: `useContext` to pass `t` to components that need it.

Comment: @marzelin That will work !. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Would the following work?

```
//custom hook returning action creator that is dispatched for you
export const useTest = () => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const thunk = React.useCallback(
    ({ key1, key2 }) => (dispatch) => {
      try {
        cogoToast(t('Hello'));
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    },
    [t],
  );
  //if you just return thunk here then your component should do:
  //const test = useTest();
  //  onClick={()=>dispatch(test(arg))}
  //here we return a function that will dispatch it for you
  return React.useCallback((arg) => dispatch(thunk(arg)), [
    dispatch,
    thunk,
  ]);
};

const Component = () => {
  const dispatchTest = useTest();
  return <button onClick={dispatchTest}>click me</button>;
};
```